# Editing Config files in phpmyadmin to create new user

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have to provide seperate phpmyadmin interface to each user of my website on localhost. I want to do it using php script. To achieve it I need to new create user accounts not from phpmyadmin interface but by editing actual configuration files and entering data there like username, password, previlages etc.

So do anyone know how t edit config files to add new users for phpmyadmin and each user will be able to see only his own databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's no such thing as a phpMyAdmin user](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#a-word-about-users), what you're talking about are MySQL user accounts. As a result, the user accounts are not stored in a configuration file, it's stored in the MySQL database itself. You can create MySQL users through many different tools and aren't limited to using phpMyAdmin to do so. I would suggest using any scripting language that connects to MySQL to directly run the [SQL queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) (such as Python on PHP) -- that way you can integrate it in to your workflow with as much automation as you care to script.

phpMyAdmin can help you quickly get the proper SQL syntax; from the Users tab of the main page simply click the "Export" button corresponding to the existing user who has the permissions you want to use. The proper SQL is presented for you to copy and paste in to your script.

Based on what you describe, you might want SQL similar to

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB';    
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `foo`.* TO 'foo'@'%';
```

Note that if your MySQL authenticates against PAM, there are a lot more existing tools for creating users, but that's a feature of the commercial version of MySQL so your availability may vary.